# postgresql mapping many to many returns error

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hi I'm looking for some helpful tips for my current mapping. It returns the following error when I tried to add the migration. I'm not too sure what I did wrong, or this is not how I'm supposed to map them.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot create a relationship between 'Brokers.ManifestToBrokers' and
>   'ManifestToBroker.ACASBroker', because there already is a relationship
>   between 'Brokers.ManifestToBrokers' and 'ManifestToBroker.ABIBroker'.
>   Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

I have 3 tables, Manifest, ManifestToBroker, Brokers.

```
public class Manifest
{
    public virtual ManifestToBroker ManifestToBroker { get; set; }
    .......other stuff
}

public class ManifestToBroker
{
    public virtual Manifest Manifest { get; set; }

    public int ManifestId { get; set; }

    public int? ABIFilerId { get; set; }

    public int? ACASFilerId { get; set; }

    public int? AMSFilerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Brokers ABIBroker { get; set; }

    public virtual Brokers ACASBroker { get; set; }

    public virtual Brokers AMSBroker { get; set; }
}

public class Brokers
{
    [StringLength(32)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Contacts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BrokerType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SupportABI { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SupportACAS { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SupportAMS { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ManifestToBroker> ManifestToBrokers { get; set; } = new List<ManifestToBroker>();
}
```

I have put all the mapping in ManifestToBrokerMapper for simplicity.

```
public class ManifestToBrokerMapping : IntKeyBaseBaseEntityConfiguration<ManifestToBroker>
{
    protected override void ConfigureThis(EntityTypeBuilder<ManifestToBroker> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
        builder.HasOne(m => m.ABIBroker)
            .WithMany(m => m.ManifestToBrokers)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ABIFilerId);
        builder.HasOne(m => m.ACASBroker)
            .WithMany(m => m.ManifestToBrokers)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ACASFilerId);
        builder.HasOne(m => m.AMSBroker)
            .WithMany(m => m.ManifestToBrokers)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.AMSFilerId);
        builder.HasOne(m => m.Manifest)
            .WithOne(m => m.ManifestToBroker)
            .IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(m => new { m.ManifestId, m.ABIFilerId }).IsUnique();
        builder.HasIndex(m => new { m.ManifestId, m.ACASFilerId }).IsUnique();
        builder.HasIndex(m => new { m.ManifestId, m.AMSFilerId }).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, Brokers table also need to contains each of the ManifestToBroker

```
public virtual ICollection<ManifestToBroker> ABIFilerMTB { get; set; } = new List<ManifestToBroker>();

public virtual ICollection<ManifestToBroker> ACASFilerMTB { get; set; } = new List<ManifestToBroker>();

public virtual ICollection<ManifestToBroker> AMSFilerMTB { get; set; } = new List<ManifestToBroker>();
```